# How do I reverse escapeshellarg?

Tags: php, escaping

Well, header says it all.
in php, how do I reverse [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/escapeshellarg)()?
To be more precise, what is the built-in function (if there is one) that will reverse it.

Comment: There isn't an official way. Explain what you're trying to do so we have some context.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I get `)(grallehsepacse`, see http://codepad.org/RCeIbFC0

Comment: @hakre I want to give you a high five for that one

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I can't think of a situation when this could be really necessary?

Comment: Could be [the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/164291).

Comment: @hakre why is it matter what I have, what I have works. I would assume there is some kind of built-in function in php to reverse its effects, like json_encode/decode urlencode/decode addslashes/stripslashes etc 
One which I could not find. May I assume there is none?

Comment: @ItayMoav: Yes, I can confirm you that there is none. I actually made a joke (the second part), the "what have you tried so far?" is asked so you share more info what you actually want to learn about (because sharing own code often makes it more clear than a thousand words). Please add the operating system you're looking for to your question. Also better describe "reverse" and I think this needs a test-suite (at least it will make it much easier to solve your problem). Also it's not yet known for what you need that, please answer that question as well (this is important), see xy problem etc. .

Answer (score 5):

Most thorough route would be to find out [exactly what escapeshellarg() does](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/exec.c#php_escape_shell_arg) and do the opposite.  In a linux environment, it looks like it's just taking care of single quotes.  In a Windows environment, it's doing a bit more.  Your reverse function should take that into account as well.

Regarding a built-in function:
The short answer is "there isn't one."  The long answer is: there isn't one because escaped shell arguments aren't ever intended to get parsed by PHP (why escape them in the first place?) so nobody ever wrote one and submitted it as a patch to PHP.  If you're passing arguments into a CLI PHP application, you don't need to unescape things as that was done already by the interpreter.

Comment: Didn't know that this uses `mb_` functions.

Comment: @hakre I didn't either until I looked that up.  =)

Comment: Thanks, but I already have code to reveres effects, was looking for a built-in function.

Comment: @ItayMoav The bigger question would be (like stated in the comments on your question) why do you want to do it?  You might not even need to do this.

Comment: @ItayMoav: There is no built-in function - or better worded: who needs that? There is no use for such a function. So that's actually what makes everybody wonder here. If you share why you need it (motivation) that would be good to know. Also if you already have code, please share it with your question. We're all sharing here, so  give your "best".

Answer (score 0):

Usecase: 
When creating a command, all args have to be properly escaped. But when using `PS` to find if that command is executing, the quotes are stripped. So a comparison is difficult.
In the case where the only programs to check are the ones started by php saving the `PID` is ok, but if we have to take into account processes which have been started from other means, it is more difficult